# IE/FF-compatible HTML table with fixed header and footer, scrollable vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, html-table

I need an HTML super-table of a sorts. It's fine if it's based on jQuery or some other JavaScript library. In fact I don't really care what the drawbacks are provided that the following requirements are met.

Must support:

1. At least IE8 and the most recent version of Firefox
2. Variable-width columns (no pre-defined widths)
3. A fixed header **and** a fixed footer
4. Both horizontal **and** vertical scrolling

I've found a whole bunch of them that satisfy some or many of these requirements, but not a single one that satisfies all of them.

Does such a thing exist? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be "almost" possible, apart from one thing: if header is fixed (i.e. unmovable) you can't scroll it horizontally. If you have horizontal scrolling, then it involves header, body and footer and it can be achieved by placing any grid in a container with the attribute *overflow: scroll*.

If that solution would be acceptable, jQuery FlexiGrid should do the trick. I haven't tried though, just thinking about possibilities.